# New Python Install; Scripts Running very Slow

Tags: windows, python-2.7, nltk, naivebayes, unsupervised-learning

Current Python Version 2.7.10 - I have tried a straight download from python.org and the Anaconda distribution.

Previous Python Version was 2.7.x (don't remember) - I know it was an Enthought Canopy distribution.

I just 'upgraded' windows from 7 to 10pro. I reinstalled everything on my computer for a fresh start. I installed the most recent version of Python 2.7.10. I am now running a script that I was running just yesterday on my Windows 7 OS, and it is running incomprehensibly slow now, and I have no idea why. It is a script that is based on the code from a tutorial found here:

http://pythonprogramming.net/sentiment-analysis-module-nltk-tutorial/

It has a lot of data that is loaded, and it wasn't running super fast before, but now it takes so long, it looks like it's frozen. Any thoughts? I thought that it had something to do with packages that I had installed on my previous Python environment, like a C-compiler or something. The output is nothing, because it just hangs for a long time and slowly moves through the script. It isn't broken, there isn't a loop it's stuck in. If I wait long enough, it will start showing me the correct output. When I hit 'Ctrl-C' this is what I get.

```
python -mcProfile MAIN_Tutorial_2.py
forrtl: error (200): program aborting due to control-C event
Image              PC                Routine            Line        Source
KERNELBASE.dll     00007FFB485B5674  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
KERNEL32.DLL       00007FFB49412D92  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
ntdll.dll          00007FFB4B819F64  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
```

Don't think that helps, but just in case.

Answer (score 0):

I've been struggling for a while with similar topic - long start up time of python scripts.
This is what I've found on python documentation site: 
[Why does Python sometimes take so long to start?](https://docs.python.org/2/faq/windows.html#why-does-python-sometimes-take-so-long-to-start)

> The problem may be caused by a misconfiguration of virus checking software on the problem machine. Some virus scanners have been known to introduce startup overhead of two orders of magnitude when the scanner is configured to monitor all reads from the filesystem. Try checking the configuration of virus scanning software on your systems to ensure that they are indeed configured identically. McAfee, when configured to scan all file system read activity, is a particular offender.

Unfortunately, I don't have a quick way to test whether disabling file system protection will help, so I hope it will solve your problem and will be glad to hear from you.